# How to import a web component in TypeScript (Vue externalised)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I export a component with a command.

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc-async --name foo 'src/components/*.vue'
```

In the [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component), it is very clear that the component will depend on an import from Vue.js in the main application.

**I have a Vue.js application with TypeScript, how can I export my Vue instance globally to the component?**

Component:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <p>footer</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Footer extends Vue {
  @Prop() private msg!: string;
}
</script>
```

**Note**: Vue-cli was used to create the main application.

Comment: to make sure you are not asking for `--inline-vue` ? You ask how to use that build component?

Comment: I would like to know how to make the Vue instance available globally for the web componet.

Comment: declare global {
  interface Window {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    Vue: any;
  }
}

window.Vue = Vue;

Comment: another important point, how to import this web component? I added it to the index.html at the end of the body tag, would that be the only solution?